# .Net core: Set a user as logged in and authenticated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, ldap, identity

If I'm using Identity (core), can I programmatically set a logged in user?

We have an app that requires the user to be able to either login via standard Identity (user email and password) or, alternatively, be able to log in via provided AD details - not all users are internal so they'll use identity, other want the ability to use it.

So... I'm using the Novell LDAP library and am able to selectively query our AD using the login details given and ascertain whether the provided credentials are valid. Given they are, I can lookup an associated user in the AspNetUser table.

Can I programmatically set the logged in user to this identity?

I.e. given a 'user' returned from the AspNetUser table, how can I programmatically set this user as the currently logged in and authenticated user?

Comment: We have a similar need and we have created 2 entry point /login and /loginAD and it is the client responsibility to attempt a /loginAD and if it fails a /login providing proper credentials. On such sensitive part of the server, you want to keep it simple and safe as possible, so I wouldn't advise creating a complicated piece of code on the server.

Comment: Thanks. All our users will be in the AspNetUser table, whether they sign in via normal Identity or via their AD credentials.

I can match the user from the AD credentials, I just don't know how I set a user in the AspNetUser table as logged in and authenticated.


E.g. I want the "setuser" equivalent of 
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User); when I already have the userid

Comment: It might depend on the authentication service you have put in place. But, the most standard way will be something like that: you create a principal and ou sign it in. ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
                new List<Claim>{
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                    ...
                }, "");

await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(AuthSchemeName, principal);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically signin User like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager
        , SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }        
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn()
    {
        //get user name from AD
        //query identity user by username
        var username = "test@outlook.com";
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        //sign in user
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
        return Ok();
    }        
}
```

**Note**

After signining by above code, you can get the `User Identity` for next sub-request.

Comment: can you do something like this inside of a middleware? Can I inject the SignInManager in middleware?

Comment: I want to programmatically log in a test user before each request.